# Android Studio Error- failed to resolve support-v4:24.0.0

Tags: android

Greeting
I am new to Android Studio and I run my app and I got the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support: support-v4:24.0.0-beta1
```

I need to know the reason behind this error and how to fix it.

Can any Android Studio expert help me in this?

THANKS

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.andoid.support: support-v4:25.3.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Provide the code necessary to reproduce your error.

Comment: Do you really have a space in the dependency string? Remove the space.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know the reason behind this error

In your module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`), you have a line like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
```

I do not know why you are requesting an out-of-date beta of this library.

> how to fix it

Change the version number to something more current. Ideally, you set your `compileSdkVersion` to be 25, then use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

as version 25.3.1 is the now-current version of this library.

Comment: I get the same error, but for the new version
Failed to resolve: com.android.support: support-v4:24.0.0

Comment: @user3315201: Then your Android Support Repository is either out of date or otherwise does not contain `24.0.0` (which also is not a good version choice). Go into the SDK Manager in Android Studio, into the SDK Tools tab, and ensure that your Android Support Repository (towards the bottom of the list) is installed and up to date (47.0.0 at present).

Comment: I have check SDK manage and I found that Repository is installed and up to date i.e. 47.0.0. So, what is the solution now?????

Comment: Go into wherever you installed the Android SDK on your machine. Look in `extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support-v4/`. See what version numbers are listed in there. Choose one of those (e.g., `25.3.1`, as I suggested).

Comment: I have checked and 25.3.1 is there. So, what is the next?
I appreciate you support.

Comment: @user3315201: In your module's `build.gradle` file, change your `compileSdkVersion` to 25, and change the version number for the `support-v4` dependency to `25.3.1`.